Many-to-Many RNN from Scratch by Pytorch
I have a problem implementing many-to-many RNN from scratch in Pytorch.
I'm using the ner-dataset on Kaggle.
The first five rows of this dataset are like this:


Firstly, I use a pre-train embedding model, named GoogleNews-vectors-negative300 to convert each word of a sentence to a 300-dim vector. So the shape of the input is (num_sentence, max_length_of_setence, input_size=300).

Secondly, I convert the labels into numbers. Because each word of a sentence must belong to one label, the shape of the target is (num_sentence, max_length_of_sentence).

Thirdly, I build a RNN model like this:


class RNN_Layer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, activate='tanh'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        self.x2h = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.h2h = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        
        self.act_func = nn.Tanh()
        if activate == 'relu':
            self.act_func = nn.ReLu()
            
    def forward(self, curr_input, prev_hidden=None):
        if prev_hidden is None:
            prev_hidden = torch.rand(curr_input.shape[0], self.hidden_size)
        
        curr_output = self.x2h(curr_input) + self.h2h(prev_hidden)
        return self.act_func(curr_output)

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, activate='tanh', device='cpu'):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.device = device
        
        self.x2h = RNN_Layer(input_size, hidden_size, activate).to(self.device)
        self.h2h = {}
        for idx in range(1, num_layers):
            self.h2h[idx] = RNN_Layer(hidden_size, hidden_size, activate).to(self.device)
            self.add_module(f'h2h {idx}', self.h2h[idx])
        self.h2o = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size).to(self.device)
        
    def forward(self, input, prev_hidden=None):
        '''
        input: (batch_size, max_len, input_size)
        output:(batch_size, max_len, output_size)
        '''
        
        if prev_hidden is None:
            hidden = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, input.shape[0], self.hidden_size).to(self.device)
            pre_hidden = torch.rand(self.num_layers+1, input.shape[0], self.hidden_size).to(self.device)
        
        output = torch.Tensor().to(self.device)
        for word in range(input.shape[1]):
            for layer in range(self.num_layers):
                if layer == 0:
                    hidden[layer] = self.x2h(input[:, word, :].float(), pre_hidden[layer].float())
                else:
                    hidden[layer] = self.h2h[layer](hidden[layer-1].float(), pre_hidden[layer].float())
                pre_hidden[layer] = hidden[layer]
                
            output = torch.cat((output, self.h2o(hidden[-1]).unsqueeze(1)), dim=1)
        return nn.Softmax(dim=2)(output)

I think the problem is that I got confused with the output shape.
In my opinion, because for each word of a sentence, this is a multi-class classification problem, the output must be a vector with the value i-th of the vector is the probability that the word belongs to class i. So for all sentences, after predicting, the output shape should be (num_sentence, max_length_of_setence, num_class).
But when I implement it as in the above, the output's shape is not the same as the target shape. So I can't calculate the cross-entropy loss.
So I have tried to detect the class in which each word is predicted by model(X_train).argmax(dim=2).float(), but I got another bug RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn.
I have tried to find an example code for this problem. But they are for many-to-one or one-to-one RNN. Some of them are for many-to-many, but they use the available modules from PyTorch, like nn.LSTM or nn.RNN.

the output's shape do not same with the target's one what is the output shape then? You should provide the code to compute loss too. And argmax of course is non differentiable as it return the index of the max element.
